# How can I fix "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Tags: javascript, php, css, zend-framework, socialengine

I use `Social Engine 4.8.11` and when I use `Google PageSpeed Insights`, I have this message :

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>
> Your page has 36 blocking script resources and 11 blocking CSS
>   resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

How to do this in `Social engine` with all my plugins?

Comment: I don't know much about what social engine code would be but if you have javascript as part of header, that could be what is causing the issue. You might want to move the js files to the end, within the body tag if this is possible.

Comment: For css, you can check if there is any @import and replace them, try these if possible https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking-css.html